# How to compile my OMNeT++ model with -Wextra compiler options

Tags: omnet++

It is easy to add the `-Wextra` compiler option to the `CFLAGS_RELEASE` and `CFLAGS_DEBUG` variable in the `Makefile.inc` file, but the OMNeT++ headers themselves generate a lot of unused-parameter warnings and the model's own warnings are buried between them. Is it possible to stop OMNeT++ throwing these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the OMNeT++ build process to treat the OMNeT++ header files as system headers.

Add this at the beginning of the `CFLAGS_RELEASE` and `CFLAGS_DEBUG` variables in `Makefile.inc`: `-isystem $(OMNETPP_INCL_DIR) -Wextra`

It will ensure that files in omnetpp/include directory are treated as system headers and will not throw any warnings no matter what warning level you set  for the model.